# Can we add multiple values on balloon marker with image in ios-charts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-charts

I am using ios-charts and i added one value to balloon marker,
now i wish to add two values in two line in balloon marker and also wants to add two dots before that two values, i have implemented it in objective c.

I want to change balloon marker font color as well

So is it possible to implement in iOS charts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's definitely possible, but how easily you can do it is what you need to think about.

Balloon marker is just a example of how to use `ChartMakrer`. You can of course sub class `ChartMarker` and make your own.

I would consider render all your values and dots into one image, and assign it to `ChartMarker`'s image property.

Comment: Is it possible to add more values to marker? Generally, it shows the actual value of the entry value (for example: 9000). I need to show the actual value of the entry(9000), time, count, and price in that. If yes, how? do you have swift sample? Should I use **chartValueSelected** to achieve my goal?

Comment: marker can show anything you want as long as you prepare the data. You need to figure out how to pass them into marker. e.g. subclass chart marker and modify `draw()` to draw your values

Comment: Thanks a lot Wingzero